# Stockfish: How to do so it only gives hints to one color

Tags: stockfish, macos

When using Stockfish it gives options/hints for both white and black. How do I make it so it only shows hints of moves for black? I am using mac.

Comment: I think you're talking about Stockfish For Mac.

Comment: You'll need to recompile the Objective-C source code. Do you have Xcode installed?

Comment: @StudentT There is no easy way of doing this? Guess I'll stick with lichess engine...

Comment: I don't think so, but someone else might know.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want this so that you can train against the engine by playing the suggestion for black and then thinking about what to play as white?

Lichess allows this on their website. Set up a position in the board editor or analysis board, then pick "Practice against computer". If you like, it will even evaluate your moves as you go, telling you if you made a mistake, blunder, a good move but not the strongest move etc.

I often do this because too often I reach a winning position and then go on to squander my advantage. I go back to the winning position and see how to actually convert it.

Comment: While I think this answer is at least somewhat helpful, it is worth noting two things. 1. The OP was looking for a Mac-Stockfish specific solution and (as a clarification) 2. lichess uses Stockfish as their engine.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Stockfish within a database program and pick the "play against engine" option.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I did not dislike this by the way.

Comment: You can use SCID, chessbase or chess assistant which are all database software programs to do this.  SCID is open source and free. There are also free with fewer options for the programs.   Just follow the instructions..